# Best way to remove the very last carriage return in StreamWriter.WriteLine c#

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have bellow code:

```
SqlDataReader Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (Rdr.HasRows)
{
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\Test.txt"))
   {
      while (Rdr.Read())
      {
          writer.WriteLine(Rdr["Item1"].ToString() + Rdr["Item2"].ToString());
      }
   }                        
 }
 Rdr.Close();
```

`WriteLine` adds a carriage return every time, but I need to avoid that when the last line is reached.

I found bellow code to know when the SqlDataReader is in the last line, where at that point I can change the `WriteLine` by `Write` which does not add the carriage return:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    var loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        //1. Here retrive values you need e.g. var myvar = reader.GetBoolean(0);
        loop = reader.Read();
        if (!loop)
        {
            //You are on the last record. Use values read in 1.
            //Do some exceptions
        }
        else {
            //You are not on the last record.
            //Process values read in 1., e.g. myvar
        }
    }
}
```

Any other idea to do this in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved with simple flag and separate `Write` / `WriteLine`:

```
bool first = true;
while (Rdr.Read())
{
    if (!first) writer.WriteLine();
    writer.Write(Rdr["Item1"].ToString() + Rdr["Item2"].ToString());
    first = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're talking about the comment `//1. Here retrive values you need e.g. var myvar = reader.GetBoolean(0);`, and that you don't want to create intermediate variables for all separate columns.

That's very feasible, because there's no much use to do that in the first place. You can simply use the `HasRows` property to see if there's something to read *after* you just read the previous row, and if so, write a newline.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Build the line you want to write
    string lineToWrite = reader["Item1"].ToString() + reader["Item2"].ToString();   

    // Write the line without carriage return
    writer.Write(lineToWrite);

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write a carriage return just before writing a new line for all lines except the first line. Your code should look something like this:

```
if(reader.Read())
{
    // write first line without carriage return in the beginning
}
while(reader.Read())
{
     //write a carriage return
     // ... and then write your line
}
```

Comment: The OP does _not_ want a carriage return for only the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I like to do in situations like this:

```
SqlDataReader Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (Rdr.HasRows)
{
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\Test.txt"))
   {
      string eol = ""; 
      while (Rdr.Read())
      {
          writer.Write("{0}{1}{2}", eol, Rdr["Item1"], Rdr["Item2"]);
          eol = Environment.NewLine;
      }
   }                        
 }
 Rdr.Close();
```